# How can I keep track of the packages to check any strange behaviour

Tags: privacy, firewalls

I've just realized there was a girl that asked someone to hack my computer and also my telephone (that's why WhatsApp was working strange). Right now I'm trying to protect myself at least on my computer. I'm trying to keep track of my network to understand any pattern despite the common packages like launchd, spotify and mac updates, etc. 
The reason I'm doing this is because I have a youtube channel and I don't want to have problems with my account or she boycotting my work. This might sound very childish and it is, so I apologize in advance.

The computer I'm using is a Macbook, I have the firewall activated, my computer with a username and password, but when I scan the ports and only scan the first 1000 and return only http is open. I'm also trying to configure the share options as I've never use them. Also I tried to install Snort on my computer but I couldn't, so I only use Etthercap (wireshark) to see about the packages (because netstat is not working properly). I understand Wireshark has a lot of features but that's something I will have to learn.

Anyway if someone could advice me with Snort, Suricata, Wireshark or any general advice I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is far too broad to answer. You're asking about too many things at once. Your biggest threats are someone getting physical access to your computer and someone emailing to an attachment or a phishing email. Also, I noticed that you don't list an anti-virus on your list of protections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as setting up SNORT goes, here is a video I found on Youtube that may be helpful (it appears to be difficult to set up):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ic07nBoweg

It appears you would want to at least practice good computer security to make being hacked more difficult.  As far as tracking packages, I am not aware of what the best solution is, but it sounds like what you are looking for would be an Intrusion Detection System, and/or a file integrity checker.  For your situation, I would especially recommend "good computer security" to include at least the following:

- Make sure you have a firewall turned on.  Note: you can also configure your firewall to be more secure, but do your research here first if you choose to do so because this can be tricky and can "break" things if you are not careful.  It appears you have already done this.
- Make sure you have antivirus software installed and updated and set to update itself, and run a full scan.  Set up a periodic scan schedule if it is not already set up.
- Change your passwords (in case you have already been hacked), and change them to long passwords (harder to hack).  Adding numbers and special characters to your passwords helps make them harder to hack too (although some sites don't seem to deal well with special characters in passwords).
- Keep your programs up to date (especially internet browsers).  Vendors continue to patch security holes that hackers can use as they are found.
- Keep backups of your files (e.g. on an external hard drive).
- In e-mail, don't follow links or download attachments unless you know who they are from, and you need to do so.  Verify "urgent situations" with the actual place of business.
  Here is an example of a phishing attempt and how to avoid it: an attacker pretending to be your bank sends you an e-mail that says they are going to close your account unless you go to the link and "verify your account".  Do NOT follow the link.  You should first verify that it really came from the place of business (e.g. visit your bank and make sure they really sent that).  Furthermore, in this example, you should report it to the bank as a phishing e-mail once they verify that they did not send it.  Usually, e-mails like that are from scammers / hackers, etc... and you should not do what they say.

There are many more things you can do to increase your security, but this list is a good start (e.g. fairly easy and adds considerable security).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you recommend me anything to have something secure? I think I have a share screen troyan on my computer as well as a Man In the Middle. Any idea I can get rid of this without formatting my computer?

Comment: Antivirus software can usually clean up malware infections, but it is not 100% guaranteed.  I would need some clarification as to what is going on with the "Man in the Middle" attack to know how to mitigate it.  Antivirus should remove any malware on your system that may be assisting in this attack.  Do you have a server that is hosting a website or something, or a regular Macbook?

Comment: As far as what antivirus to use, some Macs apparently have built in antivirus, see the end of the accepted answer at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62835/should-i-get-an-antivirus-for-my-mac