# What could this set of IDS alerts be (DDNS deaftone.com darktech.org chatnook.com, ...)?

Tags: ids, snort

Below is a screeny of my `Squert` GUI showing the `Snort` events. Notice they all happen at the same exact time. I cannot figure out what the source of it could be. Any ideas?

[image]

Edit: It looks like the domains are owned by [DtDNS](http://www.dtdns.com/dtsite/faq).

Edit 2: Here's another screeny with more details. It looks like its UDP protocol and port 53.

[image]

Comment: FYI, the second screen shot is too small to see.

Comment: Try going directly to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNfZ4.png.

Comment: All these alerts say, in and of themselves, is that DNS queries to those domains occurred. That particular provider providers Dynamic DNS services. Dynamic DNS can be used for malicious purposes, but is also used for other reasons an IP can't be static. Do you have any other details about this host around this time? I would recommend checking DNS logs, and DHCP logs as well if you aren't sure which host this is.

Comment: @theterribletrivium I know what host it is and I tracked down the PCAP file, but I have no idea what process produced the query. The contents of the PCAP file are simply: d4c3 b2a1 0200 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 ffff 0000 0100 0000.

Comment: Do you have DNS logs available? You may be able to determine that these entries were looked up for an innocuous reason by viewing what else happened around that time.

Answer (score 1):

One idea (though it may or may not be correct) is that malware on your system could be trying to reach out to its creator (e.g. to send out information or to allow for your system to be used in a botnet).  The * is typically used as a "wild card".  For example, the domain www.abc.3d-game.com should be found by the *.3d-game.com query. The domains shown here definitely look suspicious.  I would update your antivirus and run a scan of your system to check for any malware.  Even a clean virus scan does not entirely rule that idea out.

Edit: For a Mac, you may be able to use Apple's file quarantine system, see the question:
[Should I get an antivirus for my Mac?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62835/should-i-get-an-antivirus-for-my-mac)

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a virus scanner on my Mac. Any suggestions? Also, do you think some Javascript could have run from a web page I had open to do the DNS lookups? I have no idea what produced the UDP query.

Comment: @TimMolter I edited my question to address Macs as well.